# remote debug unmanaged code

Tags: visual-studio-2008, native, remote-debugging

I have a process that contains C# code, C++\CLI code and native c++ code.
Now, I'm trying to remote debug my process, and I can go to the statements of my C# code and my C++\CLI code, but I can't reach my native code.

When I try to hit a breakpoint in my native c++ source file, I get the "No symbole have been loaded" error. I tried to manualy load the symboles (tools->options->debugging), but no luck.

Any Idea?

Comment: Did you try to select Code Type manually in "Attach to Process" dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Debug: Attach To Process dialog, look for the Attach To: field about middle of the dialog.  This is where you can select whether to attach to the target process using the native debugger, managed code debugger, script debugger, etc.  The default usually gives preference to managed code, I believe.

You can't debug native code and managed code at the same time.  To debug native code, you'll need to explicitly select Native code when you attach to the remote process.